# Error: Impossible to build a BDD FSM with infinite precision variables

Tags: nusmv, nuxmv

I just installed nuXmv and wanted to try out the example growing-counter-integer from the examples folder. When I try to run the command: `build_model`, I get the error message:

> file growing-counter-integer.smv: line 30: Impossible to build a BDD FSM with infinite precision variables

Does somebody know how to fix this error? Thanks in advance.

growing-counter-integer.smv file:

```
MODULE main

VAR state : { s0, s1, s2, s3 };

VAR c : integer;
VAR lim : real;

ASSIGN
 init(state) := s0;
 next(state) :=
  case
   state = s0 : s1;
   state = s1 : s2;
   state = s2 & c < lim : s2;
   state = s2 & c >= lim : s3;
   state = s3 : s1;
   TRUE : state;
  esac;

 init(c) := 0;
 next(c) := (state = s2 & next(state) = s2)?(c+1):(0);

 init(lim) := 2;
 next(lim) := (state = s3 & next(state) = s1)?(lim + 1):(lim);

INVARSPEC c < 3;
INVARSPEC c < 4;
INVARSPEC c < 5;
INVARSPEC c < 6;
INVARSPEC c < 20;

LTLSPEC G F (state = s3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the input model contains some **infinite-domain variable**, like the `real` and `integer` types in your model, the end-user is supposed to use the [`MathSAT5`](http://mathsat.fbk.eu/) engine back-end instead of the regular approaches (like, e.g., those based on BDDs).

The commands based on [`MathSAT5`](http://mathsat.fbk.eu/) are easily identifiable in the [nuXmv manual](https://es-static.fbk.eu/tools/nuxmv/index.php?n=Documentation.Home) by the fact that they have the keyword `msat` in them. In this case, you are limited to *invariant* and *LTL* Bounded Model Checking. There are special commands also for simulating the system (i.e. `msat_pick_state` and `msat_simulate`).

After `read_model -i <file.smv>`, one would typically use the command `go_msat` and then select the appropriate approach for checking the given properties.

[image]

(slide taken from [here](http://www.patricktrentin.com/pages/fm2018.html))